# Why am I getting warning about type assignment in Typescript 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this function that I use to merge two objects of same type:

```
export function mergeObject<T>(currentObject: T, updatedObject: Partial<T>): T {
  const newObject: T = structuredClone(currentObject);
  if (!updatedObject) return newObject;
  return { ...newObject, ...updatedObject };
}
```

and this is how I use it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { mergeObject } from '@/utils/helpers/ObjectHelper';

type MyType = {
  booleanValue: boolean;
  stringValue: string;
  numberValue: number;
};

function MyTestComponent() {
  const [state, updateState] = useState<MyType>({
    booleanValue: false,
    stringValue: 'hello',
    numberValue: 123,
  });

  const updatedState: MyType = mergeObject(state, {
    stringValue: 'hello world!',
  });

  return <></>;
}
```

However I get the following warning for `updatedState` (I am using WebStorm):

```
Initializer type {stringValue: string} is not assignable to variable type MyType
```

[image]

However the error goes away if I explicitly cast the return value of `mergeObject` as `MyType`:

```
  const updatedState: MyType = mergeObject(state, {
    stringValue: 'hello world!',
  }) as MyType; // no error now
```

AFAIK, this started happening when I upgraded to Typescript version 5 (currently I am using version 5.0.3).

The questions that I have are:

1. Why am I seeing this error with Typescript version 5? I did not get any errors when I was using Typescript version 4.
2. Is there any way I can get the error go away without doing explicit type casting? May be change something in `mergeObject` function?
3. If the answer to #2 is no, will there be any downside/side effects of doing explicit type casting using `as` keyword?

Any guidance regarding this will be highly appreciated. If more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Could you make the [mre] not depend on lodash/react unless they are of vital importance to the issue  (and if they are, then tag the q with both of them)? Also could you make sure that you are asking a single primary question?  Asking a series of questions risks closure with a reason of "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: [Works for me.](https://tsplay.dev/WJV46W) In my experience, WebStorm really likes bugging out about non-existent TypeScript errors.

Comment: Additionally [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://tsplay.dev/w224Yw) so ‍♂️ how we should proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz - Thank you for your comments. I have updated my question and removed `loadash` and `cloneDeep` with [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Comment: Sorry...my bad! Forgot to hit the save edits button. Looks like an issue with WebStorm only. Let me delete the question for now and come back if I am able to reproduce this in VS Code as well.

Comment: React isn't necessary to reproduce this either. You can simplify the problem (even though it's not reproducible right now) to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB8jpW).

Comment: I’m only able to reproduce it with React only. With simple Typescript code, it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is happening because TypeScript5 has introduced stricter rules for object literal types. When you pass an object with fewer properties to `mergeObject`, TypeScript infers its type as Partial, which means it may or may not have all the properties of the type T. When you try to assign the result to a variable of type T, TypeScript expects the returned object to have all the properties of T, but it may not actually have them. You can explicitly define the return type of `mergeObject` to be the same as the type of the input objects to fix this but it is generic here.

Comment: This isn't what's going on.  Just like in your other deleted answer, there's no evidence that TypeScript 5 introduced stricter rules for object literal types (certainly nothing of the sort is mentioned [in the TS5.0 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/)).  If you are paraphrasing an answer you got from ChatGPT without independently verifying it, you [might get banned](//stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). If you are coming up with this on your own, it's still not correct.  Please remove this answer and engage more appropriately in the future.